# Python Program for Number of elements with odd factors in a given range

Tags: python, for-loop, integer, numbers, range

Given any random range we need to find Python Program for Number of elements with odd factors in a given range.

I did not understand the question itself hence couldn't try for the code for given question.
Help me with question understanding and the solution for the same.

Comment: Is "Given any random range we need to find Python Program for Number of elements with odd factors in a given range." the actual syntax of the original question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Every number that is not a power of two has at least one odd factor. So the question doesn't really make sense unless you're suppose to figure out the power of two thing.

Comment: I tried but I couldn't find more specifications for this ,I will again  try to get back with the more specifications once I get them. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

This codes returns all values, found in an array, that has only odd factors.

```
# Import modules
import numpy as np
# -------------- #

# Given a range of values
values = np.arange(0.0, 51.0, 1)

# Function to caclulate factors of a particular number
def get_factors(x):
     results = []
     for i in range(1, x + 1):
          if (x % i == 0):
               results.append(i)
     return results

# Determine the factor of all values
factors = [get_factors(int(value)) for value in values]

# Function that outputs True if all numbers in given list are odd.
def check_odd(lst):
     for num in lst:
          if (num % 2 == 0):
               return False
     return True

# Determine the indices of all elements having odd factors
indices_odd = [i if check_odd(factors[i]) else None for i in range(len(factors))]
indices_odd = np.asarray(indices_odd) # Convert to array

# Determine the number of with odd factos
num_odd_factors = len(np.where(indices_odd != None)[0])
```

I hope this is what you want...

Answer (score 0):

I would interpret the question as follows:

A factor for a number is an integer which divides that number without a remainder.

E.g.
The factors of 4 are: 1, 2 and 4.
The factors of 6 are: 1, 2, 3 and 6.

Note that 4 has an odd number of factors (3) whilst 6 has an even number of factors (4).

I think the question is asking you to write something which will list all the numbers with an odd number of factors in a given range.

E.g. if the range is 3 to 6 (inclusive), I would expect only the number 4 to be returned as 3, 5 and 6 all have an even number of factors